# mysql return distinct values from one column, group by another column with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view called '**videos**' with the following columns:

```
email(varchar)
time(varchar)
page(varchar)
```

The view has rows for every time a person with a given email visited a page.

I want to return results that show for each email address, a count of how many days they visited at least one page, and a count of how many distinct pages they visited regardless of date.

One of my issues is probably that the time is stored as a varchar. Here is an example of the format the time is in.

2016-01-25T14:36

Answer (score 3):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to extract and interpret the date-portion of your `time` string. Use `COUNT` with the `DISTINCT` keyword to count only distinct dates and distinct pages.

```
SELECT email
     , COUNT(DISTINCT STR_TO_DATE(time, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS visit_days
     , COUNT(DISTINCT page) AS visit_pages
  FROM videos
 GROUP BY email
;
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I wasn't sure how to do two separate counts in a single query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by  fro the count of the visit by day

```
select email,  date(time), count(*)
from mytable 
group by email, date(time);
```

and

```
select email,   count(distinct page)
from mytable 
group by email;
```